# How to set an element's background-color to the value of that element's class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to have the class of the span become the background-color of the same span using jQuery. Is there any way to do so?

```js
$(function() {
$("span").css("background-color")
});
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border: solid #0a0a0a 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="red"></span>
<span class="red"></span>
<span class="red"></span>
<span class="blue"></span>
<span class="silver"></span>
<span class="black"></span>
<span class="black"></span>
<span class="silver"></span>
<span class="grey"></span>
<span class="silver"></span>
<span class="green"></span>
<span class="lightgreen"></span>
<span class="gold"></span>
<span class="yellow"></span>
<span class="yellow"></span>
<span class="yellow"></span>
<span class="yellow"></span>
<span class="yellow"></span>
<span class="yellow"></span>
<span class="gold"></span>
<span class="gold"></span>
<span class="gold"></span>
<span class="red"></span>
<span class="red"></span>
<span class="red"></span>
<span class="red"></span>
<span class="green"></span>
<span class="green"></span>
<span class="green"></span>
<span class="green"></span>
<span class="lightgreen"></span>
<span class="lightgreen"></span>
<span class="green"></span>
<span class="green"></span>
<span class="gold"></span>
<span class="gold"></span>
<span class="orange"></span>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a function as the second param which can return the name of the class

```js
$(function() {
  $("span").css("background-color", function() {
    return this.className;
  })
});
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border: solid #0a0a0a 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="red"></span><span class="red"></span><span class="red"></span><span class="blue"></span><span class="silver"></span><span class="black"></span><span class="black"></span><span class="silver"></span><span class="grey"></span><span class="silver"></span>
<span
class="green"></span><span class="lightgreen"></span><span class="gold"></span><span class="yellow"></span><span class="yellow"></span><span class="yellow"></span><span class="yellow"></span><span class="yellow"></span><span class="yellow"></span><span class="gold"></span>
  <span
  class="gold"></span><span class="gold"></span><span class="red"></span><span class="red"></span><span class="red"></span><span class="red"></span><span class="green"></span><span class="green"></span><span class="green"></span><span class="green"></span><span class="lightgreen"></span>
    <span
    class="lightgreen"></span><span class="green"></span><span class="green"></span><span class="gold"></span><span class="gold"></span><span class="orange"></span>
```